# CSS Rules that have Values with None/Zero

Tags: css

I'm currently trying to make a code more concise. There are several style rules that have a value of none or 0, such as border: none; or padding: 0 0 0 0;. Are these necessary to have? Or can they be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely dependent on where in the CSS these rules are appearing. As Madeline Hanley said they could be at the start of the CSS as a browser reset or normalise (to ensure that the elements appear the same across all browsers).

In other situations `border: none;` might be doing nothing in others it could be overriding a style from another class or an inherited style where border is set.

The other risk with removing them is that someone may be relying on the `padding: 0 0 0 0;`.

There's no way to know if those rules are necessary or can be deleted without seeing the whole site and how it has been implemented, it's a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what browser you and/or your users are viewing the site from– try linking a reset.css sheet above your custom css sheet. This will reset the default style of whatever browser people are using to access the site and help ensure it appears uniform. Copy-paste this code into a sheet called "reset.css" and link above your custom one in your html file(s): https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the  html tag holding your content , some elements have padding , margin and border with them.for example;

```
<ul style="list-style"> <button style="border"><a style="text-decoration">` `<input style="border;outline">`
```

**but if you don't want them, you can define them globally in CSS3 as "none"**